# Strange SpriteKit Texture Atlas Generator Error -- Texture Atlas Failure With Exit Code 11

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, texture-atlas

I have a repeated, strange error. I'm working with a distributed team through github, and recently a developer added another .atlas folder to our project. None of the other atlases have issues, but this one is especially touchy.

The error is a SpriteKit Texture Atlas Generator Error:

`Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools/../usr/bin/TextureAtlas failed with exit code 11`

We get the error especially often after pulling from the repo, but it's relatively random. I'm currently dealing with an error where it runs on the simulator but fails on the device. It can be fixed by a combination of: changing target (we have 2), cleaning build and derived data, or changing the atlas in some way.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213422/textureatlas-tool-not-reading-texture-atlas-spritekit-texture-atlas-generator) has a similar issue, but none of the answers have worked for us, nor feel like they should.

For reference, we're all running Xcode 6.1, 10.9.5. This error didn't exist before we upgraded to 6.1, nor before the new atlas existed.

Full error:

`Generating texture atlas from Edify\ Testing/Supporting\ Files/Images/OctopusAnimation.atlas
    cd /Users/rl/Desktop/New-SAS-iOS-Pull-Post-Recursive-Instruments/sas-ios/SASL
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools/../usr/bin/TextureAtlas /Users/rl/Desktop/New-SAS-iOS-Pull-Post-Recursive-Instruments/sas-ios/SASL/Edify\ Testing/Supporting\ Files/Images/OctopusAnimation.atlas /Users/rl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Edify_Testing-gmlkyrdadlkzskdiwylbjhegbdeo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Edify-Testing-Debug.app`

**Update**

Latest commit works on 2 developer's devices (after clean), but not a 3rd developer's device.

Comment: You could try running the Textureatlas tool from the command line (not sure of its exact name but it's something like TextureAtlas or TexturePacker). Maybe that gives more hints. It certainly gives you more control over the parameters passed to the tool. One possibility is of course an image that's too large, ie over 4096 in any dimension.